# What is the programming language used for developing iOS/iPadOS?

Tags: ios

in which programming language iOS and iPad OS are written. I am just trying to understand it. Not finding proper answers.

Comment: Objective-C, Swift, C++ or C.  Generally.

Comment: @trojanfoe I believe the question is about the language(s) used to write iOS/iPadOS itself, not for developing for those OSes.

Comment: iOS/ iPadOS/ Any Apple OS actually been developed based on Unix-Like/ Darwin based ecosystem. So, generally the core modules are mostly in C, C++ but apple used Objective-C as well (since it is their primary in-house language) and gradually using Swift this days I believe.

Comment: @rmaddy I believe I am still right.  The core BSD/Mach O/S would have been developed in C and C++ and the frameworks in Objective-C and Swift.

Comment: Yes @rmaddy, you are right. The question is about the languages used to develop the Xcode, iOS SDK, etc...

Answer (score -2):

Apple usually programs its apps in Objective C. Android apps are programmed in Java.